# how to synchronize two Eclipse parts using Jface

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, e4

I found problem in synchronizing two Eclipse parts using databinding, I have used one model between two part class contains text boxes and both classes bind with that model.

For Part one:

```
DataBindingContext databindingcontext = new DataBindingContext();
textLeft = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
textLeft.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
IObservableValue iobservableModel = PojoProperties.value("name").observe(new Name());
IObservableValue observablevalueLeft = WidgetProperties.text (SWT.Modify).observe(textLeft);
databindingcontext.bindValue (observablevalueLeft,iobservableModel);
```

Model:

```
public class Name {
    public static String static_strName;

    public String getName() {
        return static_strName;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        static_strName = name;
      }
}
```

for Part 2:

```
DataBindingContext m_databindingcontext = new DataBindingContext();
textPart2 = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
textPart2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
IObservableValue iobservableModel = PojoProperties.value("name").observe(new Name());
IObservableValue observablevaluePart2 = WidgetProperties.text (SWT.Modify).observe(textPart2);
m_databindingcontext.bindValue (observablevaluePart2,iobservableModel);
```

Comment: What is "problem"? I don't really see where you are using one model for both parts. Each time you call .observe, you provide a new instance of class Name, is that correct?

Comment: Above mentioned program is not working properly, and new instance of class Name is correct because "public class Name { public static String static_strName;" is mentioned with Model.   
`public class Name { 
public static String static_strName; 
public String getName() 
{
    return static_strName;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    static_strName = name;
  }

}`

Comment: one more thing on the first time written text is appearing on text box of second part but after switching of parts it not works... means synchronization is only done for the first time for second parts and i want synchronation between two text boxes which exists in two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You need PropertyChangeSupport

```
DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
textLeft = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
textLeft.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
IObservableValue observablevalueLeft = SWTObservables.observeText(textLeft ,                    SWT.Modify);
IObservableValue iobservableModel = BeansObservables.observeValue(modelChangeRegistry,     "name");
bindingContext.bindValue(iobservableModel, iobservableModel , null, null);

public class Name extends AbstractPropertyRegistration {

    public static String static_strName;
        public String getName() {
        return static_strName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
       static_strName = name;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractPropertyRegistration {
private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new       PropertyChangeSupport(this);
public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener   listener) {
propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
}
public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener   listener) {
propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
}

protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object   newValue) {
propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
}
}
```